# What are the differences between "I am retired" & "I was retired"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

In [dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/retired):

> re‧tired /rɪˈtaɪəd $ -ˈtaɪrd/ ●●○ adjective
>
> having stopped working, usually because of your age
>
> a retired teacher
>
> Both my parents are retired now.

So,  "I am retired" = "I have just retired", isn't it?

but let say "I retired 5 years ago & I haven't been doing anything since then.", then how do I say?

**"I am retired"** or **"I was retired"**

Similarly, when to say **"he is dead"** and **"he was dead"**?

Answer (score 2):

> So, "I am retired" = "I have just retired", isn't it?

No. "I am retired" just means the speaker no longer works. There is no implication at all that the retirement happened recently. In fact, there's a very weak implication that it did *not* happen recently, because if it had, "I just/recently retired" might be more common.

> but let say "I retired 5 years ago & I haven't been doing anything since then.", then how do I say?

"I'm retired."

> I was retired.

Either you *used to be* retired (not working), but changed your mind and started working again; or, you are referring to a time in the past and saying you were retired even at that past time.